# Binary Search Tree - unique values in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

The project is to add words to the to each nodes in the BST.
I need to count the number of unique or distinct values in my BST.

Here is my code for Adding the words. I need help with writing 
int distinctWords() const;.

```
void WordTree:: addPrivate(WordNode *n, ItemType v)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        root = new WordNode(v);
    else if (v == n->m_data)
    {
        n->m_count++;
    }
    else if (v < n->m_data)
    {
        if (n->m_left != NULL)
        {
            addPrivate(n->m_left, v);
        }
        else
        {
            n->m_left = new WordNode(v);
        }
    }
    else if (v > n->m_data)
    {
        if (n->m_right != NULL)
        {
            addPrivate(n->m_right, v);
        }
        else
        {
            n->m_right = new WordNode(v);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have 2 ways: travel the tree to compute the value, or store it as member and updating the value with insertion/removal of word.

Answer (score 0):

With that tree, that's the same as the number of nodes.

Determining the number of nodes recursively:

- If the tree is empty, it has no nodes.
- If it's not empty, it has one more node than the sum of the number of nodes in the subtrees.

In C++,

```
int distinctWords(const WordNode* node)
{
    return node == nullptr 
           ? 0 
           : 1 + distinctWords(node->m_left) + distinctWords(node->m_right);
}
```